# Automate Selenium scripts on Maven build tool and TestNG testing framework

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am currently using Selenium with JUnit testing framework and Jenkins build tool with Ant. Can anyone suggest me a good tutorial where I can learn to use and implement Selenium, TestNG and Maven in my project?

I searched online but couldn't get a combination of all the above and with good practical and useful examples.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TestNG tutorials**

http://howtodoinjava.com/java-testng-tutorials/

http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/testng-tutorials/

**selenium TestNg Maven Tutorials**

http://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-selenium-integration-example/

Hope this helps you...Kindly get back if you need any further help